# After uninstalling bacula the services and files still remain

Tags: apt, server, backup

I installed bacula the other day but after some careful deliberation I concluded that it was a little robust and more than I needed for my backup needs.

So I went to remove the application with the following commands:

sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bacula-server

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove bacula-server

Everything seemed to go fine but after running sudo service --status-all I am still seeing startup service:

[ + ]  bacula-director
 [ - ]  bacula-fd
 [ - ]  bacula-sd

I must be missing something but I am not sure what.

I also have folders that still remain in /etc/bacula

I am not a Linux newbie but I am a little stumped on what I am missing. Andy suggestions on what else I need to do would be much appreciated.

Also, and suggestion on some other backup software that would work with a hybrid Linux, Pi, and Windows network. I currently have a QNAP NAS.

Thanks in advance.

-DM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable/remove the bacula services, you can do the following:

> sudo systemctl disable bacula-director bacula-fd bacula-sd

The command above should disable all bacula services of systemd. If it doesn't work, do these commands individually. (Example: *sudo systemctl disable bacula-director* and then the other services)

> sudo rm -r /etc/bacula

And finally , the command above erases *all* configuration files for bacula.

If you want to erase more bacula-related files, you can do *sudo rm /example/bacula/bacula.conf* (for a file) or *sudo rm -r /example/bacula* (for a folder). If there are configuration files on your home directory you can erase the files without doing the command with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks I think it worked. Oddly though after running that command and then checking services they are still listed. When I try to run: sudo service bacula-director stop if get daniel@sys76-gazelle:~$ sudo service bacula-director 
No bacula-director SQL package installed

Comment: Also, when I run dpkg -l | grep bacula I'm getting: rc  bacula-common                                               7.0.5+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1                                                       amd64        network backup service - common support files
rc  bacula-common-sqlite3                                       7.0.5+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1                                                       amd64        network backup

Comment: @littlebobbytables You can do `sudo systemctl stop <service name>` to stop the services from running. Now they won't startup again. Then just remove these extra packages that you found.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. I agree and that is exactly what i did. I ran sudo systemctl stop bacula-director after removing the packages. But the service still states that it is running. It's weird! I've tryied whereis bacula and nothing was found. I've removed the folder. I noticed that init.d still lists those services. I've run nmap on local host and don't see the postgres service running so I am a little lost.